# Query in cloud Firestore and php

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get

I want to do query in firestore but getting this error

```
Undefined method 'orderBy'.
```

My coding is

```
$collectionReference = $db->collection('Test3')->document('User1');
$query = $collectionReference->orderBy('Name')->limit(1);
$snapshot = $query->snapshot();
```

Why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$collectionReference` is NOT a CollectionReference; it's a DOCUMENT reference (hence the `->document('User1')`).

`->orderBy` applies to COLLECTION queries.  *If* you are trying to get the 'Test3' collection you need to use:

```
$collectionReference = $db->collection('Test3');
$query = $collectionReference->orderBy('Name')->limit(1);
$snapshot = $query->snapshot();
```

I **ALSO** don't see a `->get()` - I don't use PHP (anymore), so I don't know if it's implied in the syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, now I can continue my work

Comment: If I want to get field value in document, then what should I code? I did not found any code about that?

Comment: As I said, I don't use PHP at all - you may perhaps want to study the the documentation for the basics.  If you have a specific question about a specific issue, you can return to StackOverflow and post that question...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides